# MAC OS: How to schedule execution of Jmeter Script through Crontab/cronjob on mac os

Tags: macos, cron, jmeter

Hi I would like to know how to schedule JMeter script execution through Cronjob for different time intervals on Mac OS.

1. I have created a Jmeter script  which is UseCase1NEWUSERSTAGETestPlan file under path : /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/NewUserloginAPIonSTAGE/UseCase1NEWUSERSTAGETestPlan.jmx
2. I have created a cronjob file which has commands to execute the Jmeter file(UseCase1NEWUSERSTAGETestPlan.jmx). Path : /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/Cron/JmeterExecution.sh

   The JmeterExecution.sh has code for executing jmeter file and generating logfile as below:

> sh jmeter -n -t /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/NewUserloginAPIonSTAGE/UseCase1NEWUSERSTAGETestPlan.jmx -l /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/NewUserloginAPIonSTAGE/UseCase1NEWUSERSTAGETestPlan.csv

3. I have created a crontab/cronjob which is as below:

> 23 16 3 9 2 /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/Cron/JmeterExecution.sh  23 16 3 9 2 /Users/suneelkumar/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/Cron/JmeterExecution.sh

while executing it,It is getting as below:

> sh: jmeter: No such file or directory

Can anybody suggest me that what I made mistake in above steps and what is accurate way of executing Jmeter scripts through cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a job into crontab like this
Open crontab using command

> EDITOR=nano crontab -e 
>   or 
>   nano crontab -e

after that insert command running JMeter into crontab

```
* * * * * cd /home/user/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin && ./jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l testplan.jtl
```

then save the crontab and check the log or response

Comment: Nice, if my post is helpful, you can vote my answer.